# Problem about a homomorphism of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $G=\langle a \rangle$ is n-order cyclic group, and $K = \langle b \rangle$ is m-order cyclic group.
>   Prove the following:
>   $m\mid nk \Leftrightarrow \exists \varphi : G \rightarrow K $ is homomorphic and $ \varphi (a)=b^{k}$.

My Doubts:

It seems we need to construct a $\varphi$ but I can't find  it. How to relate it to the $m|nk$ and what does the later one illustrate?

Note: Ny fault, $G'$ and $K$ is misused and they are same.

Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a homomorphism $\varphi : G \rightarrow K$ with $a=b^k$, then
$$
1 = \varphi(a^n) =  \varphi(a)^n = b^{nk}
$$
and so $m \mid nk$.

Conversely, if $m \mid nk$, then the map $\varphi : G \rightarrow K$ given by  $\varphi(a^i)=b^{ik}$ is a homomorphism. This part is easy:
$$
\varphi(a^i a^j) = \varphi(a^{i+j}) = b^{(i+j)k} = b^{ik} b^{jk} = \varphi(a^i) \varphi(a^j)
$$
 The main issue here is that $m \mid nk$ is needed for $\varphi$ to be well defined:
$$
a^i = a^j \implies \varphi(a^i) = \varphi(a^j) 
$$
For this to happen, we need $i \equiv j \bmod n \implies ik \equiv jk \bmod m$. The hypothesis $m \mid nk$ ensures this is true.

Answer (score 1):

To define an homomorphism $\phi : G \to K $ we only need to know $\phi(a) $ .

So $\phi$ is a homomorphism :
 $$\Leftrightarrow 1 = \phi(a^n) = \phi(a)^n = b^{kn} \Leftrightarrow  \text{ord}(b) = m \mid kn$$